# Excel - working with row grouping

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a nicely formatted Excel-2007 worksheet that contains 5 separate summary tables, each with it's own title placed above the table. The tables have many rows and columns, so I have applied row groupings so each table can be individually expanded or hidden from view. When fully collapsed, only the table titles are visible giving the user the option to expand and see only the table of interest. The problem I have is the the "+" symbol used to expose the rows of each table is at the bottom of the grouping and directly adjacent to the title of the next table down. So to see the contents of table 1, the user needs to hit the "+" symbol next to the title of table 2 etc etc. Not intuitive to use.

Is there a simple trick to get the "+" symbol next to the relevant table title??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a feature introduced, I think in Excel 2010, that allows for this.  If I'm right and it isn't available in 2007, then the answer to your Q is "it can't be done"

[image]